# Some questions about Gallery widget

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery, android-gallery

1.I wish my gallery widget can dispaly 6 images at the same time, and the layout is a 2*3 matrix, and when I slide the screen, the widget display another 6 images, how to code this function?

2.I want to add some dots under the gallery widget to show which page the gallery is displaying, is there a widget can achieve this function?

3.I know hot to load pitcures in the res/drawable, but if my pitcures are in a database, how to load them?

4.I want to add some buttons to set the gallery widget to display different category images, how to code?

thx for your answer!!

Comment: And my android version is 3.1

Comment: Are you reading pictures from server or phones database? If you are reading pictures from database you should save pictures location in database and when you read it you will need to get that picture from the location witch you stored